# How to connect to git on a VPS server?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, vps

This is probably a real beginner's question, but I am drowning a bit in the huge sea of tutorials that all seem to be missing one or two vital steps...

I have an ubuntu VPS server with ssh access. I got ssh access working with a key pair so I don't have to type a password every time I connect.

I have installed git on the VPS, and I have created an empty git repository  in an empty 'test1' folder using

```
git init --bare my-project.git
```

I have created a second folder named 'test2' with a repository using

```
git init
```

Now I would like to set one of these folders as the remote for my local project, so I can use `git push` to place my files on the server (instead of using FTP to put files on the server).

I can't seem to find the proper procedure to push to this new repo. I have added the remote to my local project using:

```
git remote add origin ssh://myname@100.00.000.000/test1/my-project.git
git remote add origin ssh://myname@100.00.000.000:/test2/
```

I have also tried cloning the remote

```
git clone ssh://myname@100.00.000.000/test1/
```

When pushing or cloning I get the error:

'not a valid git repository - make sure this is a valid repository and that you have access permissions'

What step am I missing here?

Comment: git clone is the rigth way. https://git-scm.com/book/fr/v1/Les-bases-de-Git-Travailler-avec-des-d%C3%A9p%C3%B4ts-distants Your git repository maybe corrupted ! Have you created a user from git on the VPS server ?

Comment: No I haven't... I will try that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for the leading `/`. It is interpreted as a root of filesystem, which is not probably what you want:

```
git clone ssh://myname@100.00.000.000:test1/
```

Also `ssh` is default, so doing `myname@100.00.000.000:test1/` should be enough.